# Callback after PJAX request is finished and has downloaded assets

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-events, pjax

An application of mine uses PJAX style navigation, which means that rather than loading the full page, we use AJAX to load a partial page and then use the HTML5 history/pushState API to update the browsing history.

Previously I was using the `window.onload` event to measure end user page loading times and I want to be able to record these times with the PJAX page loads, the problem is that this event does not fire after PJAX loads.

I have access to a `pjax:end` event which fires once the PJAX request is complete, but this is fired before all assets have finished downloading. I would like to be able to instrument the complete time it takes to download the page including the time to download extra (images/scripts) assets.

Is this possible? Is there a callback i'm missing or some magic that will allow me to measure the complete request time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that I only need to wait for images (not scripts).
A friend pointed me to this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

I'm using this code to trigger the onload event:

```
$('#main-inner').waitForImages(function() {
  window.onload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific event for a block of HTML loaded asyncronously. I think the best option is to attach your html, find each `img` and `script`, then bind to the `load` event (assuming jQuery) for each of them. When the number of loads equals the number of elements you found, then everything is loaded. I hope this helps.

```
var start = new Date().getTime(),
    elems = $('#my-div').append(html).find('img, script'),
    count = 0;

elems.on('load', function () {
    if (++count === elems.length) {
        var diff = new Date().getTime() - start;
    }
});
```